# Inter-thread inter-object communication in Swift 3 with Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, concurrency, viewcontroller, swift3

My program consists of three relatively-distinct areas: listening on a network for new state, performing network actions, and updating the UI. So respectively I want three classes: StateListener, ActionSender, and ViewController, each chugging along on separate threads.

Would that it were so simple -- the three need to interact. Some states discovered by the StateListener require Actions to be sent by the ActionSender or the UI to be updated by the ViewController. Some responses to Actions require the UI to be updated by the ViewController. Some UI actions require Actions to be performed by the ActionSender.

Currently I do something like this (pseudocode):

```
/* ViewController.swift */
class ViewController : blah
{
    //...
    func buttonPressed()
    {
        // ?! Need to do an action here but I can't 
        // because actionSender is initialised below...
    }

    func viewDidLoad()
    {
        let actionSender = ActionSender(m_view: self)
        let actionQueue = OperationQueue()
        let stateListener = StateListener(m_view: self, 
                                          m_actionSender: actionSender,                    
                                          m_actionQueue: actionQueue)
        let stateQueue = OperationQueue()
        stateQueue.addOperation(stateQueue.listen())
    }
}

/* StateListener.swift */
class StateListener
{
    // ...
    func listen()
    {
        while true
        {
            var state = waitForNewState()
            if shouldActOn(state)
            {
                m_actionQueue.addOperation(m_actionSender.act())
            }
        }
    }
}

/* ActionSender.swift */
class ActionSender
{
    // ...
    func act()
    {
        var reply = sendAction()
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation(m_view.m_textBox.append(reply))
    }
}
```

This is fairly hellish and doesn't even do what I want it to do, because I can't have the ViewController perform actions (ActionSender's require a ViewController reference to update the view after the action, but I tried initialising the ActionSender within ViewController.init and I got bizarre errors to do with a Code.init that I hadn't implemented...). I want to get *above* ViewController and initialise all these OperationQueues and objects wherever ViewController gets initialised, but I can't find where that is...

What I've done above is basically object-reference injection of each object and OperationQueue. I know there are other ways of doing this (a hierarchy of callbacks, NSNotifications) but I'm unsure of which is best.

My question is in two parts:

1. What is the best (i.e., fastest, easiest to implement and maintain, most idiomatic in Swift) way to get the inter-object and inter-thread communication I desire?
2. I currently get things going from ViewController's viewDidLoad function, which seems awful (and means I can't get a 'higher-up' perspective of the ViewController. Where should this stuff go? AppDelegate advertises itself as the 'program startup' area, but I can't access the ViewController from there... XCode seems to have hidden the startup of my app from me!

I really appreciate your responses!

Comment: This is too vague, too broad, and seems to be soliciting opinions on the "best way" to accomplish something, with not really enough information to make concrete suggestions. That having been said, you never want to spin like this, waiting for some some "state" change. You want to respond to events, and not block a thread in the process.

Comment: Re the app delegate, yeah, that's where the app starts up, and rather than the app delegate getting a reference to the view controller, it's generally the other way around, where the view controller can get the app delegate (e.g. `let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate` or `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`) and thereby get references to objects that the app delegate might be managing for us.

Comment: Rob: thanks for your comment. I tried to be as specific as I could be without muddying the waters, but evidently I failed to give enough detail. Sorry! As for the dislike for waiting for some state to change, what's the alternative? If you respond to events surely you have to listen for events? I should clarify that waitForNewState() only returns when a new state has been pushed by my server. And states will come thick and fast so a good portion of the time will be dealing with them.

Comment: Rob: Ah, so it's normal to have the ViewController basically treated as the main() of the program, where all objects are created, etc? That strikes me as peculiar and makes it rather annoying (read: impossible in some cases) to pass the ViewController itself to objects, as in my case...

Comment: For many apps, the app revolves around the UI, so it does tend to take a fairly central role. It doesn't mean that everything goes into the view controller. It's not unusual, for example, to create objects that act as controllers for specific domains (e.g. a network request manager object to create network requests and parse responses, etc.). But the view controller will often specify itself as the delegate of this network object, as it generally coordinates the process of updating the model and the UI (though not necessarily so).

Comment: Re the question getting too broad and a bit unclear, I agree that it would be unreasonable to supply all the detailed code. No offense was intended. It's just that it's going to be much easier for us to answer if the question can be narrowed (e.g. one question on how to get controller objects instantiated by app delegate to the view controller, another question on communicating between various controller objects with a small practical example of what you tried, etc.).

Comment: Rob: sorry, I hope I didn't come across as defensive -- I completely accept your criticisms and appreciate your help! :-) I'll take your point about splitting up questions on board for future posts!

Comment: No, not at all. It's just that there's so much sniping here on S.O. and people get so touchy that I wanted to make sure you weren't offended by my attempt at constructive criticism.

Comment: "As for the dislike for waiting for some state to change, what's the alternative?" ... Almost all asynchronous routines have some mechanism to inform _you_ of the state change, so rather than polling, waiting for the state change to occur, you have the code that would otherwise initiate the state change simply initiate the call to inform the interested objects of the event (via delegate methods, calling some closure, issuing a notification in the notification center, etc.).

Comment: But when the thing that's informing me is an external server, how can I use that sort of mechanism? Specifically, state updates are pushed to my app via HTTP responses. My state listener sends a request for new state which is answered when and only when there is new state. I could do the request as an async function with a callback to parse the state rather than having the stateListener waiting on an OperationQueue, but don't both involve blocking a thread under the hood?

Comment: "pushed to my app via HTTP responses" - So your app is polling, issuing requests and check the response? If so, we'd generally prefer remote push notifications or sockets, which eliminates the need to spin, checking the status. But if you have an existing, true push mechanism, then that also eliminates the need to spin. Hey, sometimes we make architectural compromises that entail spinning, but we do so with the appreciation of how inefficient that is.

Answer (score 0):

This post greatly helped with question 2 and the problem of passing self as a parameter to a data member in an initialiser : http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html

Specifically, I can use this pattern:

```
class Foo : blah
{
    var m_bar : Bar!

    init() {
        // notice I get away with not initialising m_bar
    }

    func viewDidLoad {
        m_bar = Bar(m_foo: self)
        m_bar.doYourThing()
    }
}
```

The blog prefers the following, which I feel I should add here out of gratitude to the author, though I prefer the above.

```
class Foo : blah
{
    lazy var m_bar : Bar = {
        return Bar(m_foo: self)  // notice I can pass in self
    }

    init() {
        // notice I get away with not initialising m_bar
    }

    func viewDidLoad {
        m_bar.doYourThing()
    }
}
```